# Django Bootstrap will not let me center this container

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to center this div container after my navbar so that there is an equal space on both sides of the page. But, it is not working for some reason. Can you guys help please? The post_job.html is the issue. The portion where i display the text is being rendered on the left side with a bit of text going down

Here is my code snippet:
post_job.html

```
{% load static  %}

{% include 'recruiter_navigation.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm full_width">
            <h2 style="color: darkblue;" class="text-center">Post an Internship</h2>
        </div>
   </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

recruiter_navigation.html

```
<div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        
        {% endblock content %}
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the output

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center this div

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm full_width">
    <h2 style="color: darkblue;" class="text-center">Post an Internship</h2>
</div>
```

you can add following style to `.row`

```
.row.some-class{display: flex; justify-content: center}
```

BTW if you are using bootstrap4 you are using wrong way but if it is bootstrap3 that's fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS "align-content: center" to center the content even though if that's not working then you can use center opening tag before div and center closing tag after div.

It will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from the given code is that your `recruiter_navigation.html` is not wrapped inside of a row, hence the container is aligning itself to the next parent in that dom which I believe is the body.

here is my solution

In `recruiter_navigation.html` use this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
  </div>
</div>
```